# Copying a file on linux C

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a program that simply copies an executable file in C on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int args,char*argv[]){

FILE *src1;
FILE *final;

if ((src1 = fopen("/home/exophrenik/Desktop/src1","rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open src1\n");
    return -12;
}   

if ((final = fopen("/home/exophrenik/Desktop/final","wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open final\n");
    return -32;
}   

int c;
while((c=fgetc(src1))!=EOF)
{
    printf("%d\n",c);
    fputc(c,final);
}

fclose(src1);
fclose(final);
return 0;
}
```

The program is properly compiled and it seems that it does it's job right. The only problem is that when I try to run the 'final' executable from the command line, I get the Permission Denied error. I recompiled the above program as sudo and also run it as sudo but it made do difference.
From my little linux experience I know that the Permission Denied is often encountered when you try to run a program with the ./ command but it is not an executable, like trying to open a txt file like that instead of using gedit to open it.

**My question is why do I get that same error when the only thing I do is copying an already working executable? Am I doing something wrong during the copy process that somehow corrupts the new file?**

Comment: Show us the commands you use to compile and run the result. You're likely doing something wrong. Also show us the output of running `umask`.

Comment: You probably need to set executable permissions to the newly created file (see chmod()). Another comment: to make it faster, you may read the file chunk by chunk instead of character by character (with for instance chunks of 1 kilobytes).

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comments, in Linux the executable flag of a program is implemented as a permission bit. That's why you get a _permission denied_: it does not mean that you are not privileged enough (`sudo` will not help), but that the executable permission bit is not set in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. As the others already said in the comments it was a permissions issue.

I added the following lines on the above code

```
 struct stat st;

  stat("/home/exophrenik/Desktop/src1", &st);
  chmod("/home/exophrenik/Desktop/final", st.st_mode);
```

Those lines will copy the permissions of the src1 executable and apply then to the final file making it an executable as well. They require the following header

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
```